# How to use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager to manage thousands of GET requests?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` in `httpclient` version `4.5.3` to GET an array of URLs. I followed the example described in Apache httpcomponents' [tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) section 2.4. However, I am encountering out of heap memory issue using this code:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();

// URIs to perform GETs on
String[] urisToGet = {
    "http://www.domain1.com/a",
    "http://www.domain1.com/b",
    "http://www.domain1.com/c",
    "http://www.domain1.com/d",
    // thousands more
    // ....
};

// create a thread for each URI
GetThread[] threads = new GetThread[urisToGet.length];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urisToGet[i]);
    threads[i] = new GetThread(httpClient, httpget);
}

// start the threads
for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
    threads[j].start();
}

// join the threads
for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
    threads[j].join();
}
```

For reference, the GetThread is as follows:

```
static class GetThread extends Thread {

    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
    private final HttpContext context;
    private final HttpGet httpget;

    public GetThread(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpget) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.context = HttpClientContext.create();
        this.httpget = httpget;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(
                    httpget, context);
            try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
            // Handle protocol errors
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Handle I/O errors
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried passing the connection manager into each thread and closing expired connections in the `finally` part of each thread:

```
this.connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
this.connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, this does not address the issue.

Perhaps, is it because I am creating too many threads? Do I need to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead?

Comment: `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` by default allows only 20 concurrent connections in total and max of 2 for same domain. Looks like all the 1000 connections are to different hosts. So, Try setting more total connections as you require

Comment: This is the code to increase total connections `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager 
  = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connManager.setMaxTotal(1000);`

Comment: @sairamch04 Thanks for pointing that out! I'll try that right now. However, sorry, I updated the snippet slightly the `urisToGet` contains urls to the same domain but different paths.

Comment: Then @Erik, then you need to set `connManager.setMaxPerRoute(1000)`. If you are seeing `heap memory` issue. you could increase heap or reduce the threads maybe